# Conflict when using both Sementic UI Accordion and JQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using both Sementic UI and Jquery UI. However, I want to use Semantic UI's accordion and there seems to be conflict when I call Semantic UI's accordion class.

Sample:

```
<div class="ui accordion">
  <div class="active title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    What is a dog?
  </div>
  <div class="active content">
    <p>A dog is a type of domesticated animal. Known for its loyalty and faithfulness, it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    What kinds of dogs are there?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>There are many breeds of dogs. Each breed varies in size and temperament. Owners often select a breed of dog that they find to be compatible with their own lifestyle and desires from a companion.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    How do you acquire a dog?
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Three common ways for a prospective owner to acquire a dog is from pet shops, private owners, or shelters.</p>
    <p>A pet shop may be the most convenient way to buy a dog. Buying a dog from a private owner allows you to assess the pedigree and upbringing of your dog before choosing to take it home. Lastly, finding your dog from a shelter, helps give a good home to a dog who may not find one so readily.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I used Semantic UI with jQuery UI and there isnt a problem for me.

Did you initialize your semantic ui accordion in your main.js?

```
$('.ui.accordion')
  .accordion()
;
```

Add the above code in your document load javascript function, and it should work!

```
(function($) {
    $('.ui.accordion')
      .accordion()
    ;
}(jQuery));
```

Also make sure jQuery JS is added before semantic JS.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Semantic-ui JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks IWillGetBetter for such a quick answer. i will try and let you know the result.

Comment: @SujanKumarKolli No worries. I chose Semantic UI in the end because of its clean characteristics. But the problem is it is hard to get help online. Update me if it works :)

Comment: Hi iWillGetBetter  i had creatged small project in JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/e623rjzn/1/ it taking both library..

Comment: Hi @SujanKumarKolli, dont worry. It is working now. https://jsfiddle.net/e623rjzn/3/

Comment: Remember, always put jQuery JS before all other JS.

Comment: Thanks. Its working. i had moved sementic libraries to last.

Comment: @SujanKumarKolli Good to know it works for you! Please mark as answer and upvote if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui and semantic have an `accordion`, so there is a conflict.

For fix, download from [here](https://jqueryui.com/download/) and check all **WITHOUT** accordion.

I try and it's fix.

Hope that it could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, this is a conflict between the JUI and SUI `accordion` functions.

I haven't seen any mention of the (currently closed) [item in the SUI issue tracker about this](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5304). You could weigh in there (or, better, offer a PR) if you're inclined.